# scroll controlled volume html or java

Tags: html, html5-audio

I am attempting to make a website with audio (its background music and there is no video to go with it) that gets louder as I scroll closer to the bottom of the page (the page changes in length as its updated with new text/images). But I don't know what I'm doing when it comes to audio and most other things html related. So how would I go about performing this task?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fade HTML5 audio (adjust volume) using jQuery (window).scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965034/fade-html5-audio-adjust-volume-using-jquery-window-scroll)

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried?